# .NET Core dependency injection - How to dispose manually created instances?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, servicecollection

Like the below code, I have to use the factory/func way of registration with container as I don't know the value of "userId" property ahead of time but only during runtime. This is working & no issues with functionality aspects.

```
container.AddSingleton<IBLogic, BLogic>(); //explicitly registration 'BLogic' service object

container.AddSingleton<Func<string, IDBCache>>
        (p=> (userId) => new IDBCache(userId, p.GetService<IBLogic>()));
```

Since here I'm using "new IDBCache", as per the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#services-not-created-by-the-service-container.) framework does not dispose of the services automatically.

*Questions*:

1. To make framework to dispose of the services automatically, is there any way out?
2. container.**AddSingleton**<Func<string, IDBCache>>
   (p=> (userId) => new IDBCache(userId, p.GetService()));

Since I'm just registering the definition of func/factory not the service object(like 'BLogic') as such, does AddSingleton provides any advantage over using 'AddScoped' or 'AddTransisent' like below?

```
container.AddTransisent<Func<string, IDBCache>>
        (p=> (userId) => new IDBCache(userId, p.GetService<IBLogic>()));
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no easy fix for this. MS.DI doesn't contain a `RegisterForDisposal` method that you can call. You will have to create a separate wrapper that implements disposable to which you can hook your created instances. For instance:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IBLogic, BLogic>();

services.AddScoped<DisposeWrapper>();
services.AddScoped<Func<string, IDBCache>>(p => (userId) =>
{
    var cache = new IDBCache(userId, p.GetRequiredService<IBLogic>());
    p.GetRequiredService<DisposeWrapper>().Add(cache);
    return cache;
});
```

Where the `DisposeWrapper` looks like this:

```cs
public sealed class DisposeWrapper : List<IDisposable>, IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Dispose in reverse order as creation.
        for (int i = this.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) this[i].Dispose();
    }
}
```

Such implementation, however, comes with quite some caveats, because `DisposeWrapper` should be registered using the same scope as you want to cache your `IDBCache`. That's why in the example above, I registered both `DisposeWrapper` and the factory as `Scoped`.

Registering `DisposeWrapper` as Singleton, means that created `IDBCache` instances will only get disposed when the application ends. If you create many `IDBCache` instances during the lifetime of the application, it will cause a memory leak. This is unlikely a good idea in your scenario.

Registering both as transient, on the other hand, could still (confusingly) cause memory leaks, because the factory could be injected into a singleton, causing it (and its `DisposeWrapper`) to become a [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

Because of the complications of this design, I recommend changing your design.

If you redesign `IDBCache` in such way that [runtime data isn't required during object construction](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/), you can allow `IDBCache` to be registered in the container without factory (e.g. `AddTransient<IDBCache>()`) which allows it to be disposed normally by the container. This will remove all above-introduced complexity.